# Gecko in Firefox OS simulator same as that in browser?

Tags: firefox, firefox-os, gecko, web-ide

When I start the Firefox OS simulator, does it use the Gecko of the browser, or does it use its own Gecko?

Comment: And you can change the gecko (and the gaia profile) it uses in the addons'settings btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses its own Gecko, which is located inside its installation directory, something like:

[PROFILE]/extensions/fxos_[VERSION]_simulator@mozilla.org

To find your profile directory, see [Profiles - Where Firefox stores your bookmarks, passwords and other user data](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data).